# Mongodb - Innerjoin on multiple fields from two collections

Tags: mongodb, inner-join

I am trying to learn mongodb and wanted to know if it will support an inner join on multiple fields.

What I am expecting is a mongodb query equivalent of:

```
select * from tablea A inner join tableb B on a.id = b.id and a.name = b.name
```

I tried using $match but I am not able to see any results.
These are my mongodb collections:
CountryState:

```
{
    "countryCode" : "1",
    "stateCode" : "1"
}
{
    "countryCode" : "1",
    "stateCode" : "3"
}
```

CountryStateLookup:

```
{
    "countryCode" : "1",
    "stateCode" : "2",
    "countryName" : "TamilNadu"
}
{
    "countryCode" : "1",
    "stateCode" : "1",
    "countryName" : "Kerala"
}
{
    "countryCode" : "2",
    "stateCode" : "1",
    "countryName" : "Karnataka"
}
{
    "countryCode" : "2",
    "stateCode" : "2",
    "countryName" : "California"
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "countryCode" : "1",
    "stateCode" : "1",
    "countryName" : "Kerala"
}
```

This is the following query I tried: (Dont know how to use the $match operator)

```
db.countryState.aggregate([  
   {  
      $lookup:{  
         from:"countryStateLookup",
         localField:"stateCode",
         foreignField:"stateCode",
         as:"stateCodeName"
      }
   },
   {  
      $unwind:"$stateCodeName"
   },
   {  
      $lookup:{  
         from:"countryStateLookup",
         localField:"countryCode",
         foreignField:"countryCode",
         as:"countryCodeName"
      }
   },
   {  
      $unwind:"$countryCodeName"
   },
   {  
      $match:{  
         "countryCode":"$stateCodeName.countryCode",
         "stateCode":"$stateCodeName.stateCode"
      }
   }
])
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Basically one `$lookup` only on the `countryCode` values as the one with most matches, `$unwind` the array and then remove unmatched `stateCode` with a field comparison ( `$redact` or `$project/$match` ). Or use the `pipeline` expression where you have MongoDB 3.6 and specify both constraints to match.